# Freezing Python script

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm working on a roguelike game in Python, so I was seeing if I could do something to make a function that takes in dice notation(If you're unaware what dice notation is, 1d4 would mean roll 1 four-sided die, 1d20 means roll one twenty-sided die, 2d8 means roll 2 eight-sided dice, etc.)

The idea is we run a function like `rolldice("2d4")` and have that return the cumulative result of two four-sided die rolls. So I wrote a test script to see if my idea would work. All it is supposed to do is take dice notation, roll those dice, and spit out the total and the results of each individual dice roll.

Unfortunately, however, the script seems to be freezing after inputting the dice notation.

```
from random import randint


print("PLEASE INPUT DICE NOTATION")

input_ = input()
output_ = 0

rolls = []

count = int(input_[0])
size = int(input_[2])

while count > 0:
    output__ = randint(1, size)
    output_ += output__
    rolls.append(output__)
    count - 1

print(int(output_))
print(int(output__))
```

Comment: Why are you providing a sketchy link to some makefile instead of providing a [mcve] in the question itself?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In most other communities it's advised to pastebin/hastebin your code if it's more than a few lines, so that's what I did here. I'll edit it though, I didn't realize that was what was wanted.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. That link will eventually break, and this question will become useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You are using while loop `while count > 0:` but then you don't actually reduce `count` to 0 at any point.

This will send you into an infinite loop, giving the appearance of "Freezing". 
 To fix this, instead of `count - 1` use `count = count - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't decrement the 'count' correctly

```
count - 1
```

should be

```
count -= 1
```